# How to insert an image in the linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I just wanted to insert an image in linear layout similar to this[image]
Can anyone help me with this???

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) since your picture shows something similar to that.

Alternatively, take a look at [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

Answer (score 0):

set layout's orientation to horizontal, then add 4 images in xml, one after another, add ids like image1, image2 etc, then call them in your onCreate like ImageView image

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1)
```

and so on, then you can either set "src" attribute in yoru xml or say image1.setImageBitmap or any other method available in ImageView class to set the image you want from your res/drawable/

Answer (score 0):

you can use ImageButton in horizontal LinearLayout
make background of the ImageButton @null 
then put the margins between them